# Scala Spark How can I convert a column array[string] to a string with JSON array in it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column that contains an array of strings,
I need to convert it into a JSON list of string?
original value: `[a,b,c]`
transformed value: `"[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine `struct`, `to_json` and `get_json_object`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val jsonArray = get_json_object(
  to_json(struct($"YOUR_COLUMN".as("data"))),
  "$.data"
)

df.select(jsonArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like below could also help
variableDF = variableDF.withColumn(f.name, to_json(struct(col(f.name))))